# Как хранить компонент VUE на сервере в виде строки

Tags: javascript, vue.js, spring

Есть потребность хранить полностью компонент vue на стороне сервера, стак vue + spring. Реализую функционал редактируемого шаблона, в котором есть режим превью и редактирования (редактирование на уровне кода).
Пробовал хранить каждый элемент компонента, как отдельную строку (template, props, data, methods, etc...), тогда их можно хранить на сервере а в дальнейшем создать компонент по этим полям через  Vue.component, но есть проблема с хранением объектов с функциями в виде строки. Есть ли какой-то вариант просто сохранить строку с кодом, а потом ее отрендерить как компонент? Что посоветуете? Спасибо!

Comment: посоветую server side rendering vue

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону асинхнонных компонентов https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html